# Facebook, Snapchat, WhatsApp Contacts Find Friends Feature Using AWS Mobile Hub

Tags: swift, aws-mobilehub

The feature I want to implement is like *Snapchat* or *Facebook* or *WhatsApp*, where you can find friends who are using the app, which means, a user of my app can look into their contacts to see which has used my app.

I seem to search for a lot of answers, but not sure how to implement specific to `AWS Mobile Hub`. I'm using `AWS Cognito User Pool` with phone verification method. I'm also developing an iOS App using *Swift*.

Anyone can give me a general direction where I can research. And if I can't find any answer, I would ask question, I would not flag as answered so soon, so sorry in advance first.

Answer (score 1):

AWS has published a tutorial for building a fully functional mobile social chat app for iOS (Swift) or Android. The guide, "Build a multi-user messaging app with serverless architecture using Mobile Hub" is available [here](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-mobile-messaging-app-ios/).

This 1-2 hour tutorial walks you through setting up the backend and generating a sample iOS Swift Xcode project using AWS Mobile Hub. The app is designed to be secure by default and have the ability to scale to millions of users.

The tutorial covers most of the common features of a social chat app like:

- Searching your phone contacts for active app users (matching phone
  number)
- Push notifications for real-time message notification
- File/photo sharing with the option to delete the image/photo after x
  minutes!